# Checking ends of a substring

Tags: optimization, c, algorithm, strings, palindrome

I was doing this particular problem [AIBOHP](http://www.spoj.com/problems/AIBOHP/) and used a dp approach based on checking the ends of a substring of length i starting from 1. Although my time complexity is fine at O(n^2) but space is taking too much because of which I am getting RTE if I am declaring it dynamically or TLE if I am declaring it as global static which needs to be reduced because the dp size can be 6100*6100 . Any suggestions how to optimize my below code for this purpose .

The problem statement is:

> He now asks the doctors to insert the minimum number of characters
>   needed to make S a  palindrome. Help the doctors accomplish this task.
>
> For instance, if S = "fft", the doctors should change the string to
>   "tfft", adding only 1 character.

My code:

```
static int dp[6101][6101];
main()
{
    int tc;
    scanf("%d",&tc);
    while(tc--)
    {
        char s[6102];
        scanf("%s",s);
        int len=strlen(s);
        memset(dp,0,sizeof dp);
        for(int i=1;i<len;i++)
            for(int j=0,k=i;k<len;k++,j++)
                dp[j][k]=(s[j]==s[k])?dp[j+1][k-1]:min(dp[j][k-1],dp[j+1][k])+1;
        printf("%d\n",dp[0][len-1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can reduce the memory consumption by a constant factor, but I'm not sure about reducing the space complexity. A simple hint could be: use `short int` instead of `int`, because your answer won't go more than length of your string, right?

Answer (score 6):

## Things you did well:

- Usage of `static`.
- Using `memset()` instead of some `for` loops for initialization of your `int[][]`.

## Things you could improve:

#### User Experience:

- You don't indicate to the user that they should enter a number first.

  ```
  printf("Enter the number of test cases: ");
  ```
- You don't indicate that the user should enter a string after then enter a number.

  ```
  printf("Enter test case string: ");
  ```

#### Variables:

- I don't expect `dp` will ever contain negative numbers:

  > ```
  > static int dp[6101][6101];
  > ```

  You also don't need the full range of `int`.  Using a `unsigned short` will half your memory usage.

  ```
  static unsigned short dp[6101][6101];
  ```
- Always initialize your variables when you create them.

  ```
  int tc = 0;
  ```

#### Readability:

- You don't declare what `main` will return or take in as parameters.

  > ```
  > main()
  > ```

  I know that when the type specifier is missing for what you will return, it defaults to an `int`.  You should still declare it for more readability.  Also, whenever you don't take in any parameters, declare them as `void`.

  ```
  int main(void)
  ```
- Your `for` loop is hard to follow.

  > ```
  > for(int i=1;i<len;i++)
  >     for(int j=0,k=i;k<len;k++,j++)
  >         dp[j][k]=(s[j]==s[k])?dp[j+1][k-1]:min(dp[j][k-1],dp[j+1][k])+1;
  > ```

  Braces will help, and will reduce the likelihood of you unintentionally adding bugs in the future.

  ```
  for(int i=1; i<len; i++)
  {
      for(int j=0,k=i; k<len; k++, j++)
      {
          dp[j][k] = (s[j] == s[k]) ? dp[j+1][k-1] : fmin(dp[j][k-1], dp[j+1][k])+1;
      }
  }
  ```
- Don't use the ternary operator for longer statements.

  > ```
  > dp[j][k] = (s[j] == s[k]) ? dp[j+1][k-1] : fmin(dp[j][k-1], dp[j+1][k])+1;
  > ```

  This makes it hard to follow and understand what you are trying to do.  Just use the normal `if-else` statements.

  ```
  if (s[j] == s[k]) dp[j][k] = dp[j+1][k-1];
  else dp[j][k] = fmin(dp[j][k-1], dp[j+1][k]) + 1;
  ```
- Use more space in your code.  Let it *breathe* a bit.  But don't go overboard.
- Use more comments to explain your code.

#### Syntax/Styling:

- You have some [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) in your code.

  > ```
  > static int dp[6101][6101];
  > ```

  With the help of macros, we can easily get rid of them.

  ```
  #define ARRAYSIZE 6101
  static int dp[ARRAYSIZE][ARRAYSIZE];
  ```
- Don't use the function `min()`.

  > ```
  > dp[j][k]=(s[j]==s[k])?dp[j+1][k-1]:min(dp[j][k-1],dp[j+1][k])+1;
  > ```

  `min()` and `max()` functions are not included in standard C.  To make things simple for your code, use the standard math function [`fmin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmin).

  ```
  dp[j][k] = (s[j] == s[k]) ? dp[j+1][k-1] : fmin(dp[j][k-1], dp[j+1][k])+1;
  ```
- You have an implicit conversion that loses integer precision:

  > ```
  > int len=strlen(s);
  > ```

  You aren't converting your `unsigned long` that `strlen()` returns to an `int`.

  ```
  int len = (int) strlen(s);
  ```
- Use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.  This way we can specify the maximum number of characters to be copied into our string (including the terminating null-character).

  ```
  fgets(s, 6101, stdin);
  ```
- You should always check for superfluous input and get rid of it.

  ```
  while (getchar() != '\n');
  ```

#### Preprocessor:

- Whenever you include functions such as `scanf()` and `printf()` that deal with input or output, you need included the standard I/O header.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  ```
- Whenever you include functions that deal with strings, there is a good chance you will have to include the string header.

  ```
  #include <string.h>
  ```
- Whenever you include math functions, you need to include the math header.

  ```
  #include <math.h>
  ```

## Final Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 6101

static unsigned short dp[ARRAYSIZE][ARRAYSIZE];
char s[ARRAYSIZE] = {0};
int main(void)
{
    int tc = 0;
    printf("Enter the number of test cases: ");
    scanf("%d",&tc);
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    while(tc--)
    {
            printf("Enter test case string: ");
        fgets(s, ARRAYSIZE, stdin);
        int len = (int) strlen(s);
        memset(dp, 0, sizeof dp);
        for(int i=1; i<len; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0, k=i; k<len; k++, j++)
            {
                if (s[j] == s[k]) dp[j][k] = dp[j+1][k-1];
                else dp[j][k] = fmin(dp[j][k-1], dp[j+1][k]) + 1;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", dp[0][len-1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't follow your O(_n_) algorithm at all. But isn't `i - 1 >= 0` always true?

Comment: @200_success It turns out my O(n) program was buggy.  It has now been removed.